# Can't load images using webpack and 3d models into babylon.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babylonjs

webpack and babylon.js is not loading images, videos and models. How can i fix that ?

I have already tried to do this

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("him", "Dude/", "dude.babylon", scene, function (newMeshes, particleSystems, skeletons) {

newMeshes[0].position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 5);  // The original dude
scene.beginAnimation(skeletons[0], 0, 120, 1.0, true);

dudes = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // 10 clones
    var xrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501) - 250;
    var zrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501) - 250;

    var c = [];

    for (j = 1; j < newMeshes.length; j++) {
        c[j] = newMeshes[j].clone("c" + j);
        c[j].position = new BABYLON.Vector3(xrand, 0, zrand);
        c[j].skeleton = newMeshes[j].skeleton.clone();
        scene.beginAnimation(c[j].skeleton, 0, 120, 1.0, true);
    }

    dudes[i] = c;
}
```

Comment: I use ```3JS``` for loading 3DModels.

Comment: Please, share the error log. And, does the callback get executed?

Comment: oh....it works now .. i use ...var image = require('../images/somefile.png') and then pass into Texture() it works...! do you know where i can download exporter for bablon file for blender 2.7.9? i am gonna to try to load a model as well...

Comment: babylon.js?0ab6:4 BJS - [18:40:59]: Error while trying to load image: /public/assets/images/yushan.png?07d54f8a95b8ee9be496f9819e00f61a
t._ErrorEnabled @ babylon.js?0ab6:4
l @ babylon.js?0ab6:4
error (async)
t.LoadImage @ babylon.js?0ab6:4
n.createTexture @ babylon.js?0ab6:6
i @ babylon.js?0ab6:15
createScene @ index.js?9bdc:165
startGame @ index.js?9bdc:94